# Securing the endpoints of LUIS & QnaMaker

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

What are the best ways to secure the endpoint of Cloud services such as Luis and QnaMaker?

Even, How do we secure the Rest API endpoint of the Bot as well ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want them more secure? What is the security vulnerability that you see? The endpoints are using https and LUIS/QnAMaker has it's own key and application/KB ID that needs to be known. We need more specifics on what aspect you see as "not secure"

Comment: This is the question from the customer, if someone knows the application Id and key they start using the services. How we can secure it more through any certification or token based ?

Answer (score 0):

> This is the question from the customer, if someone knows the
>   application Id and key they start using the services. How we can
>   secure it more through any certification or token based?

**Azure Key Vault** is a perfect fit for that. Find more information here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/basic-concepts
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgujSug1ZbI
- https://www.attosol.com/azure-key-vault-an-introduction-with-step-by-step-directions/
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-azure-key-vault/